# How to insert same `datetime` variable into different tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datetime

I'd like to store a `datetime` variable into different tables by using two functions. I use `constraint` in `CI` but still have no luck.

This is the constraint:

```
$date_now = date("ymdhis");
define('TODAY_DATE',$date_now);
```

These are the functions:

```
public function save_activity_m(){
   foreach($details as $rows){          

      $stock_in          = $rows['product']."_".TODAY_DATE;
      $data['STOCK_IN']  = ($rows['product'] == "") ? NULL : $stock_in;

      $this->MProduct->ins_product_m($data);
   }
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('New stock arrived');window.top.location.reload();</script>";
}

public function save_notifikasi(){

    $lampiran = $this->input->post('lamp');     

    $data['note_date'] = $lampiran."_".TODAY_DATE;      
    $data['note']       = $this->input->post('isi');

    $this->MProduct->ins_notif($data);
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You have a notification');</script>";


}
```

How to make the datetime is the same for `$data['STOCK_IN']` and `$data['note_date']`?

Comment: What database server and data type are you using? For something like MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB you'll want to use a `DATETIME` field with the date in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: You can echo the constant variable to check whether it holds same value or not.

Comment: I combine the datetime with text in the table. so I use varchar

Comment: Yeah - sorry, missed that when scanning the question :|

Comment: so the datetime in php must be the same

Comment: Are those functions in the same script or called at the same time?

Comment: @CD001 It's in the same script. The `save_activity_m` executed first though. Then, if there's a success insertion, `save_notifikasi` is executed

Comment: That's your issue then - since the first function reloads the window it cranks up a new instance - resetting the date. The web is stateless, using a `constant` won't hold that data from one page load to another - you probably want to set/check a session variable instead.

Comment: I'm open to any solution/answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the web is stateless, no data in a PHP variable will be held from one page (or load) to another; essentially you're booting the application from scratch each time.

The only way around this is to use some sort of semi-persistent storage such as a cookie or session variable (or persistent storage like the database) - setting a `constant`, e.g. `define('TODAY_DATE',$date_now);` will only make that data constant for the **current** execution of the script(s).

This is a basic example using session storage (`$_SESSION`):

```
<?php

// crank up the session
// you may well have one running already, 
// in which case ignore this
session_start();

// store the execution time for this script
// as a session variable if it's NOT already set
// i.e. don't overwrite it
if(empty($_SESSION['time_now'])) $_SESSION['time_now'] = date("ymdhis");


public function save_activity_m() {
    foreach($details as $rows) {          
        $stock_in = $rows['product'] . "_" . $_SESSION['time_now'];
        $data['STOCK_IN'] = ($rows['product'] == "") ? NULL : $stock_in;
        $this->MProduct->ins_product_m($data);
    }

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('New stock arrived');window.top.location.reload();</script>";
}

/**
 * Assuming this is the last thing you want to
 * do with 'time_now' you should unset it here
 */
public function save_notifikasi() {
    $lampiran = $this->input->post('lamp');     
    $data['note_date'] = $lampiran . "_" . $_SESSION['time_now'];
    $data['note'] = $this->input->post('isi');
    $this->MProduct->ins_notif($data);

    // since we're done with the 'time_now' session
    // variable we need to unset it...
    unset($_SESSION['time_now']);

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You have a notification');</script>";
}

// just to be on the safe side unset the 'time_now' session var 
// if it's older than 1 minute - otherwise future calls to this 
// script, by the same user, during the same session will use 
// the stored value from $_SESSION['time_now']
if(isset($_SESSION['time_now'])) {
    $sessionTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdhis', $_SESSION['time_now']);
    $oneMinuteAgoTime = new DateTime('-1 minute');

    if($sessionTime < $oneMinuteAgoTime) {
        unset($_SESSION['time_now']);
    }
}
```

The caveat is that because you've stored the time in a session variable, unless you update or unset it, it will always be there (for the current session) - so if the user runs the script again it'll just use the stored time from the session.

I've put in a couple of `unset()` calls to try and work around this.

Answer (score 0):

See [PHP: define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). It's a constant and it should have the same value if the two functions executed in the same time the script is running.

Comment: i've use it. and there is difference in seconds.

Comment: Maybe it is a configuration of the database. The row could have an **DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** or **ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**. Maybe?

Comment: The default format for datetime is: **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**

Comment: sorry, I mean varchar.

Comment: Do this: **$date_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");**

Comment: @AndreasRex ... you're making the same mistake I made - the date isn't being stored as a date, but appended to another string, so the format is irrelevant - my initial thought was the `TIMESTAMP` thing as well.

Comment: I do not want the (-) and (:) int the table. I combine the text with datetime without space, (-) and (:)

Comment: The two functions are called separate. Each function recalls the define (create a new constant) and have different times. I mean the script is called 2 times. 1 time with the **save_activity_m()** and second time with **save_notifikasi()**.

Comment: @AndreasRex any suggestions to make the datetime is the same each function?

Comment: You could use a third table. Store the datetime with a id generated from **save_notifikasi()** and use this information in **save_activity_m()**. A solution with **Cookies** is not secure. Or you can access the data with sql in **save_activity_m()** which is generated in **save_notifikasi()** without using a thrid table.